# Can you have nested classes in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm not talking about inheritance. And I'm not talking about *nested objects*. I'm talking:

```
System::Web::Templating(...)
```

kind of nesting. These are classes of which you shouldn't create instances.. so...

Comment: Dude, that's [**chaining**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4414422/632951), not nesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

However, you could do something like this by returning an instantiated object in getInstance():

```
myClass::getInstance()->foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

nope, you can’t nest classes in php. see: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/10138-nested-classes-php

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're speaking about namespaces, not about any kind of nesting. This feature was implemented in PHP 5.3, and is documented [here](http://php.net/namespaces).

Comment: namespaces and nested classes are different things. Although in other languages the syntax of calling can be the same both for namespaces and classes